# Using history mixin in ES6?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code, how do I refactor the mixin? I heard you can get around certain things using this.context, but am not certain how it can be applied in this case. I don't get why ES6 wants to kill mixins... some backwards compatibility would be nice.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, History} from 'react-router';

var SearchGithub = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ History ], //not sure what to do with this
    handleSubmit: function() {
        var username = this.refs.username.value;
        this.refs.username.value = '';
        this.history.pushState(null, '/profile/'+username);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-12">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-7">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="username" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-5">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-block btn-primary">Search Github</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**React router have a dedicated section in the [History docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/fe9358adc864c556afff6fd472476ab84ce2d7d9/docs/api/History.md#but-im-using-classes) file which explains how to use history with classes.**

If you look at way the [history mixin is implemented](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/History.js), then you'll see that it's just a wrapper that gets hold of the history variable from context.

With your class, you can just do this yourself.

```
import PropTypes from 'react-router';

var SearchGithub = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit() {
    // ...
    this.context.history.pushState(null, '/profile/' + username);
  }
});

SearchGithub.contextTypes = { history: PropTypes.history };
```

Alternatively, you could take a look at [react-mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin), which provides an interface for using mixins with ES6 classes.

```
import { History } from 'react-router';
import reactMixin from 'react-mixin';

var SearchGithub = React.createClass({
  // ...
});

reactMixin(SearchGitHub.prototype, History);
```

There are some good reasons that the class interface for React was [designed without mixins](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750).

Comment: Thanks, in your opinion, is not using react-mixin the more "proper" way to do things?

Comment: If it was the proper way to do it, the class interfaces would have supported it by default — in my opinion.

Comment: I just get afraid that ES6 will have a random large change, not get widely adopted, etc outside of react and a handful of projects.

Comment: I don't think there's any risk of ES6 not being widely adopted, especially given the toolchains like Babel that we already have for working with it. However, classes are going to be difficult, but as the React team pointed out — ["we never told you to use ES6 classes"](https://twitter.com/soprano/status/610867662797807617).

Answer (score 0):

Another way that the react-router folks suggest is by using *props*:

If you aren't happy using  createClass  for a handful of components in your app for the sake of the  History  mixin, have a couple of options:

•Pass  this.props.history  from your route components down to the components that need it.

One of the other options is Dan Price's response above (which leads me wondering: "What's the point in using context instead of props?")

Source Link: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/fe9358adc864c556afff6fd472476ab84ce2d7d9/docs/api/History.md#but-im-using-classes